# Pandas error "Length of values does not match length of index" when concatenating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, concatenation

I have this 'Length of values does not match length of index' error popping up and breaking my code.

Here the code is to loop through a dictionary to pull out parameters and path to send to an api to update information within the path objects.

My code is failing after the first iteration and I do not know why.

Here is the code:

```
import dydx3 as dy
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

dir = os.getcwd()

client = dy.Client(
    host = 'https://api.dydx.exchange'
)

markets_1m = {'BTC-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\BTC-USD_1MIN.csv', 
           'ETH-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\ETH-USD_1MIN.csv', 
           'LINK-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\LINK-USD_1MIN.csv',
           'SOL-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\SOL-USD_1MIN.csv',
           'ATOM-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\ATOM-USD_1MIN.csv',
           'XMR-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\XMR-USD_1MIN.csv',
           'RUNE-USD':f'{dir}\\markets\\RUNE-USD_1MIN.csv',
           }

def get_price_data_1m():
  try:
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

    StartedAt = []
    UpdatedAt = []
    Market = []
    Resolution = []
    Low = []
    High = []
    Open = []
    Close = []
    BaseTokenVolume = []
    Trades = []
    UsdVolume = []
    StartingOpenInterest = []

    for ticker, path in markets_1m.items():

        candles = client.public.get_candles(
            market = ticker,
            resolution ='1MIN',
        )
        for i in candles.data['candles']:
            startedAt = i['startedAt']
            updatedAt = i['updatedAt']
            market = i['market']
            resolution = i['resolution']
            low = i['low']
            high = i['high']
            open = i['open']
            close = i['close']
            baseTokenVolume = i['baseTokenVolume']
            trades = i['trades']
            usdVolume = i['usdVolume']
            startingOpenInterest = i['startingOpenInterest']
            StartedAt.append(startedAt)
            UpdatedAt.append(updatedAt)
            Market.append(market)
            Resolution.append(resolution)
            Low.append(low)
            High.append(high)
            Open.append(open)
            Close.append(close)
            BaseTokenVolume.append(baseTokenVolume)
            Trades.append(trades)
            UsdVolume.append(usdVolume)
            StartingOpenInterest.append(startingOpenInterest)

        dataframe['startedAt'] = [value for value in StartedAt]
        dataframe['updatedAt'] = [value for value in UpdatedAt]
        dataframe['market'] = [value for value in Market]
        dataframe['resolution'] = [value for value in Resolution]
        dataframe['open'] = [value for value in Low]
        dataframe['high'] = [value for value in High]
        dataframe['low'] = [value for value in Open]
        dataframe['close'] = [value for value in Close]
        dataframe['baseTokenVolume'] = [value for value in BaseTokenVolume]
        dataframe['trades'] = [value for value in Trades]
        dataframe['usdVolume'] = [value for value in UsdVolume]
        dataframe['startingOpenInterest'] = [value for value in StartingOpenInterest]

        price_history = pd.read_csv(f'{path}') #input csv path

        combined = pd.concat([price_history.reset_index(drop=True), dataframe.reset_index(drop=True)], join='outer', ignore_index=True, axis=0)

        combined.drop_duplicates(subset=['startedAt'], keep='first', inplace=True)

        combined = combined.sort_values(by=['startedAt'])

        combined.to_csv(f'{dir}\\markets\\{ticker}_1MIN.csv', index=False)
    
        print("end of iteration")

  except Exception as e:
    print(f'{e}')
```

I have tried to reset the index lengths in both dataframes and ignoring the index in the concat function and that has not worked.
I have also tried to suppress the error all together using continue inside of a try/except within the main loop and that has also yielded the same error.

What I is supposed to be happening is that the function should pull the data, append that data to the existing dataframe, remove any duplicates, sort the dataframe by the 'startedAt' column, then save to the same path.

When I try to do this is only will properly execute the function for the first item in the 'markets_1m' dictionary then fail on all the rest.

Any ideas on why it only works on the first one or why is error is coming up at all?

Thanks

Comment: These kinds of questions are difficult to answer. you need to read the instructions on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The problem was that the list assembled to store the new data were not being cleared in every iteration since they were stored outside of the main function loop.

The correct code has the lists stored under the main loop so they are cleared with the start of every new iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the bookkeeping of maintaining many temporary lists. Use a defined method and list/dict comprehension for API process and data frame builds:

```py
def get_api_data(ticker):
    """
    Call API and return select values in list of dicts.
    """
    candles = client.public.get_candles(
        market = ticker,
        resolution ='1MIN',
    )

    api_data = [
        {
            "ticker": ticker,
            "startedAt": i['startedAt'],
            "updatedAt": i['updatedAt'],
            "market": i['market'],
            "resolution": i['resolution'],
            "low": i['low'],
            "high": i['high'],
            "open": i['open'],
            "close": i['close'],
            "baseTokenVolume": i['baseTokenVolume'],
            "trades": i['trades'],
            "usdVolume": i['usdVolume'],
            "startingOpenInterest": i['startingOpenInterest']
        } 
        for i in candles.data['candles']
    ]

    return api_data


def build_price_data_1m_frames():
    """
    Build and return dict of data frames.

    Export each ticker historical and current data to CSVs.
    """
    try:
        dydx_dfs = {
            ticker: pd.concat(
                [
                    pd.read_csv(path).assign(ticker = ticker),
                    pd.DataFrame(get_api_data(ticker))                   
                ],
                ignore_index=True
            ).drop_duplicates(
               subset=['startedAt'], keep='first'
            ).sort_values(
               by=['startedAt']
            ).reset_index(drop=True)        
            for ticker, path in markets_1m.items()
        }

        for tkr, df in dydx.times():
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(dir, "markets", tkr, "_1MIN.csv"))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

    return dydx_dfs
```